# wp_reset_postdata does not work for category page

Tags: wp-reset-postdata

I have a category template which displays some posts and some content generated by a plugin template, which uses `the_permalink()` to refer to the current url. The category template looks like this (`category.php`):

```
<?php $categoryQuery = get_the_category(); ?>
<?php $parentCategory = get_term_by('id', $categoryQuery[0]->parent, 'category') ?>
<?php if ($parentCategory->slug !== 'teams' && $categoryQuery[0]->slug !== 'teams') {
    get_template_part( 'archive', get_post_format() );
} else {

    get_header(); ?>

    <div class="container main-outer">

        <?php set_query_var( 'categorySlug', $categoryQuery[0]->slug ); ?>
        <?php set_query_var( 'categoryName', $categoryQuery[0]->name ); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'teams-header', get_post_format() ); ?>
<?php } ?>

...

// Here goes the plugin template

...
```

And the `teams-header.php` file looks like this:

```
...

<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$featpost = new WP_Query(array(
    'category_name' => $categorySlug,
    'showposts' => 5,
    'paged' => $paged,
));
$newnum = 1;
$maxNumPages = $featpost->max_num_pages;
while($featpost->have_posts()) : $featpost->the_post();
    ...
    $newnum++;
endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata() ?>
<div class="pagination-links">
    <br />
    <?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older entries', $maxNumPages) ?>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <?php previous_posts_link('Recent entries &raquo;') ?>
</div>
```

The problem is that the plugin template is showing the first displayed post url as the current url (with `the_permalink()`), and not the category one. `wp_reset_postdata()` should reset the current post data, but maybe I'm missing something. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it just setting `$post` to `null` after the posts render:

```
<?php $categoryQuery = get_the_category(); ?>
<?php $parentCategory = get_term_by('id', $categoryQuery[0]->parent, 'category') ?>
<?php if ($parentCategory->slug !== 'teams' && $categoryQuery[0]->slug !== 'teams') {
    get_template_part( 'archive', get_post_format() );
} else {

    get_header(); ?>

    <div class="container main-outer">

        <?php set_query_var( 'categorySlug', $categoryQuery[0]->slug ); ?>
        <?php set_query_var( 'categoryName', $categoryQuery[0]->name ); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'teams-header', get_post_format() ); ?>

        <?php $post = null; // This solves the problem and the_permalink() is the category page ?>

<?php } ?>

...

// Here goes the plugin template

...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the category id and the fetch the permalink by using get_category_link($Id);

Comment: The plugin template should not be modified, and it's what is using `the_permalink()`.

Comment: You can use condition in function.php and modify the_permalink() with get_category_link() if current page is category page

Comment: This may works but also seems a bit weird. I think that it would be better to reset the post data.

Comment: you need to share me more details so I can look into further.

Comment: Well, here are all relevant details. The one left is just the plugin template call which uses `the_pemalink()`: `leaguemanager_matches(5)` from LeagueManager plugin.

Comment: try using `wp_reset_query()`

Comment: I also tried, but nothing changes.